# communicating between modules in zend framework 2

Tags: module, zend-framework2

I have an authentication module. Now, I want to ensure that every module passes (communicates) with that authentication module. I guess you could say its the authentication to the entire application. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well one simple way would be getting that module/module_class via namespaces, then you could just extend the class. Have the functionality automatically called in the parent class or call the method in the child class. This would be a pretty basic way:

```
// Auth class
class SomeAuthClass
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // go ahead and call doAuthCrap here, or wait 
        // and let the child class call it manually
    }

    protected function doAuthCrap()
    {
        // code
    }
}

use Your\AuthModule\SomeAuthClass;

class SomeOtherModuleClass extends SomeAuthClass
{
     public function zippy_snipp()
     {
          // call some method from the parent auth class (doAuthCrap)
     }
}
```

Or to adhere to some of the new ways ZF2 does things, you could access the auth class via the service manager and write the config for it in service config in your module.php file. There's really multiple ways to go about doing this one and ZF2 offers quite a bit of options for doing stuff like this.

zf2:

```
// in controller
$auth = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('someAuth');

// in service config in module.php
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'someAuth' => function ($serviceManager) {
                // code here
            },
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: So I need to do this now for every module and controller? that seems absurd. There should be an easier way of handling this.

Comment: If every class is extending some base class and the method in the base class is already called upon initialization then its not that absurd, all you're doing is subclassing. Have you looked into dependency injection as well?

Comment: Oh I see. I did not read it correctly. I will try subclassing. What is dependency injection?

Comment: I am unable to access the factory from the base controller. i set up the factory in the default application module. isnt that available site-wide? Its returning the following error: `Call to a member function get() on a non-object`

Comment: is your controller extending Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController ? That class extends the class where service locator resides, which is in Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController

Comment: or you could just implement Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface and Zend will just inject the ServiceLocator instance. Make sure you have the setter for  it though in the class that implements it.

Comment: My basecontroller is extending zend abstractactioncontroller.